# Launch an application at startup

Tags: linux, systemd, xfce4, xfce4-terminal

**Task:**

Launch xfce4-clipman at startup

**Tried:**

I've created a sh script at the right place with the right permissions:

```
martin@martin:/etc/init.d$ ls -l start_clipman.sh 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 26 мар 12 09:05 start_clipman.sh
```

Content of the sh file:

```
martin@martin:/etc/init.d$ cat start_clipman.sh 
#!/bin/bash
xfce4-clipman
martin@martin:/etc/init.d$
```

I've ran

```
martin@martin:/etc/init.d$ sudo update-rc.d start_clipman.sh 
defaultsinsserv: warning: script 'K01mount_disk.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K01start_clipman.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'start_clipman.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'mount_disk.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

**Potential problem:**

When I do this:

```
martin@martin:~$ xfce4-clipman
```

The application is running, but xfce-clipman is occupying the terminal, it's being executed, it's working but if I want to use the terminal to type something else, I have to Cancel it.

```
martin@martin:~$ xfce4-clipman
^C
martin@martin:~$
```

**What do I do**

Comment: Auto-start programs are configured in `autostart` manifests or in `*.service` files in several locations, as well as in `init.d` or `crontab`. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525845/43233

Answer (score 6, accepted):

xfce4-clipman requires access to your Xorg display (the X11 graphics system) – not just because it's indeed a graphical app, but also because it's a clipboard manager and X11 covers that as well.

The (main) problem: **Your Xorg display isn't actually available at startup yet.** It is launched *on login*, long after the system startup has finished. Therefore it's impossible to launch xfce4-clipman "on startup" – what you actually want is to launch the app on login as well.

(Linux is built to support multiple users, who can log in & log out at any time – each user gets a brand new copy of Xorg running, and the login screen itself gets one as well. So services cannot count on Xorg being available *at all.*)

#### Launching apps on login

Most desktop environments, including Xfce, can launch "login" tasks via `*.desktop` files (which is indeed how various Xfce components are launched).

They are located in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` for global services, and `~/.config/autostart/` for personal ones. After you create one, it is "enabled" by default, although can still be disabled via `xfce4-session-settings`.

In fact, even xfce4-clipman installs its own autostart file to /etc/xdg/autostart – it is named `xfce4-clipman-plugin-autostart.desktop`. It should work automatically as long as you're using Xfce4 (due to the `OnlyShowIn=XFCE` line).

But if your system is missing that file, or if you want to use xfce4-clipman in a non-Xfce desktop environment, then you can create a new one. Autostart `.desktop` files generally look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Clipboard manager
Exec=xfce4-clipman
Terminal=false
```

#### Launching non-CLI programs manually

Many desktop environments have a "Run" dialog at <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, which lets you run programs without occupying a terminal.

Various methods of doing the same *from* a terminal are:

- `(setsid xfce4-clipman 2>/dev/null &)`
- `(xfce4-clipman &)`
- `nohup xfce4-clipman &`
- `xfce4-clipman & disown`
- and so on.

#### Other problems with your init.d script

In situations where system services are apropriate, you should remember that files in /etc/init.d are not just simple scripts they're also run on shutdown, and must accept subcommands such as "stop" or "restart". When the system calls `/etc/init.d/your_service stop`, the initscript needs to actually *stop* the service – not start it again!

You've tagged the question with [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd), so why not save yourself a lot of trouble and write a native systemd `*.service` file instead? While "proper" init.d scripts can fill several screens, systemd .services are often less than a dozen lines.

Even more importantly: There are many dozens of services starting up at various points in time. At later stages, some facilities are available that earlier stages do not have. (For example, networking.)

If your initscript does not explicitly state its ordering requirements ("must run before Y, but after Z"), the OS will run it at an unpredictable stage, in parallel with everything else. If you're *very* lucky, it will run at the right moment – but most of the time it will run too early for anything to work.

In native systemd unit files, ordering is specified using `Before=` and `After=` parameters. (It's a good idea to specify dependencies using `Requires=` or `Wants=`, as well.) Meanwhile, init.d scripts (with both SysVinit and systemd) use a special comment block marked `### BEGIN INIT INFO`, with parameters such as `Required-Start:` and `Should-Start:`.